# Swift cast variable to variable class

Tags: swift

I'm trying to cast a cell to a dynamic class type:

```
struct Item {
    var cellClass: AnyClass
}


let cellClass = item.cellClass
let cell: cellClass = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

However, I'm getting an error:
`cellClass is not a type`

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`AnyClass` is defined as `AnyObject.Type`, and you cannot create an instance of type `AnyObject`, it doesn't have public initializers...

However, if you know that all the cells will be a subtype of `UITableViewCell`, you can do what you want with something like this:

```
struct Item {
    var cellClass: UITableViewCell.Type
}

class Test: UITableViewCell {
    var str = ""
}

// create an instance of Item with the class Test
let i = Item(cellClass: Test.self)

// then create an instance of Test by using the instance of Item
var t = i.cellClass.init()
```

Then, when you ask `if t is Test`, it will say `true`.